# REST query to determine which polygons geometry is inside and outside of

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

I am experimenting with feature services (ArcGIS Server) using REST.  I have a specific problem now I'd like to solve but not sure of the best way or syntax.

I have an input geometry that I query to find out which polygons in a feature services it intersects.  For this I send in a polygon as my input geometry and use 'esriSpatialRelIntersects' as the value for 'spatialRel' in the REST query.  Very nice, it works well.

However, what I want to also identify is that some of my input polygon is outside of any other polygon.
In the example below, I have three polygons. POLY C is my input geometry.  It intersects POLY A and POLY B.  However some of the polygon is over 'empty space'.

How can I determine that?

I need to know if some of the inputGeometry does not intersect the target features.

[image]

Perhaps there is a function I can use that will calculate the area that the polygon intesects others and I can compare this to the total area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the API-description: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/

Have a look at the geometry service interface. If you don't have access to your own geometry service, you could use esri's at http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer
If you have access to your own ArcGIS server but don't have a geometry service on it, you can create one on the server.

Using the various functions on the geometry service you will be able to figure out what part of the polygon is not overlapping the others. One way is to first use *union* on Poly A and poly B. Then use the *difference* to subtract the resulting polygon from Poly C. The result of the difference operation will be what you are looking for. If you want you can send that geometry to *areasandlengths*-operation the get the area, but a non-empty geometry will tell you that some part did not overlap.

Another approach would be using *intersect* and compare areas using *areasandlengths*